# Application displaying "The last time you opened_____, it unexpectedly closed..." error

Tags: crash, games

A while ago, I bought a GOG game titled "Enter the Gungeon". One day, while I was playing it, the game suddenly crashed. Now, the game had crashed before and I had opened it up again without any worries, but this time was different. Whenever I tried to open the game, I always received the same error message:

`The last time you opened Enter the Gungeon, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?`

It doesn't matter which option I choose, the program always crashes. Whenever I open the game on any other user, it works. I have tried messing with the `.plist` file of the game, restarting my computer, updating my OS, and reinstalling the game (even with updated versions). I have a MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017), and I am one macOS Mojave (version 10.14). I have 8 GB of RAM.

What could be done to fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

You might try deleting any Saved Application State for the app.

You might need to scroll through to find the correct one, as they tend to be named with the convention com.companyname.productname

From the Finder, hit  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>G</kbd>  for Go to Folder... & copy/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State/`

You can safely delete the entire com.companyname.productname folder, it will be recreated at next launch/quit cycle.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. I even tried reinstalling and doing the same thing. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Simply reinstalling almost never fixes anything. It's a Windows-fed myth, I think. You probably need to google for 'complete uninstall [app name]' to trash any remnants, which may take any game progress with it, if that's retained locally.

Comment: It still hasn't worked. I have tried a complete uninstall of the application and all supporting files, but to no avail.

Comment: I'd be inclined to contact the app developer; otherwise it's going to be a case of trying to figure out what that user account is running that no other account does & gradually eliminate potential conflicts.

Comment: great it works me on Mac

Answer (score 0):

Deleting EtG saved state worked for me to stop the "unexpectedly quit while reopening windows" message of showing, but the game kept crashing on startup.

Anyway I was able to fix it by deleting the game's cache. I used the instructions on this post of how to fully uninstall the game: https://macutility.com/Games/uninstall-Enter-the-Gungeon-58523.html to succesfully delete the game's cache by accesing the folder "Preferences" located on the folder "Library". After deleting the cache I was able to play normaly and the run I was playing when the crash happened saved. This worked for me on Mac, I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened on my Unity project on Mac and I've just solved this problem by deleting all Unity-related files inside `~Library/Caches` folder on my Mac.

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! You might want to explain how we can recognize Unity-related files...

Comment: I recognized that they were Unity cache files because simply they had 'unity' word in the filenames, so I just deleted them and suddenly this fixed my problem (Unity could finally be started)